# Mailchimp: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array

Tags: node.js, express, mailchimp

**Trying to add a member to a list but I keep getting this error: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.**

Here is the complete output-

```
Server is running on port 3000
John Doe johndoe123@gmail.com
{
  type: 'https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/',
  title: 'Invalid Resource',
  status: 400,
  detail: "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
  instance: 'd2186fc0-10d0-22af-ac4b-b04d7c6a61b7',
  errors: [
    {
      field: 'email_address',
      message: 'This value should not be blank.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the app.js file-

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const axios = require("axios");
const { response } = require("express");

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");

  mailchimp.setConfig({
    apiKey: 'rupak:ec9e6dcf527*****8655da1b-us13',
    server: "us13"
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.secondName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    console.log(firstName, lastName, email);
   
    const data = {
      members: [
        {
            email_address: email,
            status: "subscribed",
            merge_fields: {
                FNAME: firstName,
                LNAME: lastName
            }
        }
      ]
    }

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    
    let url = 'https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/20b****bce/members' ;

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        auth: "rupak:ec9e6dcf527*****8655da1b-us13"
    }

    const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
        response.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        })
    })

    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();

  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

As far as I know, the email_address field is not empty since I have logged the output of email and I can see the email that I entered being displayed.

**** **EDIT**  ****

I tried another [method](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/) but now I get this long error message that I don't understand at all

Here's a very small part of it

```
Error: Bad Request
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\Rupak\Desktop\Projects\Web Development\Newsletter-Signup\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:699:13)
    at C:\Users\Rupak\Desktop\Projects\Web Development\Newsletter-Signup\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:903:18
    at Stream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rupak\Desktop\Projects\Web Development\Newsletter-Signup\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\parsers\json.js:19:7)
    at Stream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Unzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rupak\Desktop\Projects\Web Development\Newsletter-Signup\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\unzip.js:55:12)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
```

And here's the updates app.js file

```
//jshint esversion: 6

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");

  //setup mailchimp
  mailchimp.setConfig({
    apiKey: "ec9e6dcf527*****8655da1b-us13",
    server: "us13"
  })
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var firstName = req.body.firstName;
  var lastName = req.body.secondName;
  var email = req.body.email;

  console.log(`${firstName} ${lastName} ${email}`);

  const run = async () => {
    //testing if server is working fine

    // const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
    // console.log(response);

    //add member to list
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("20b****bce", {
      email_address: req.body.email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: req.body.firstName,
        LNAME: req.body.secondName
      }
    })

    console.log(response);
  }

  run();
  
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a `members` array, while [the api you are using](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/) is only accepting one member at a time. It will probably work if you change it to:

```
const data = {
     email_address: email,
     status: "subscribed",
     merge_fields: {
         FNAME: firstName,
         LNAME: lastName
    }
}
```

Also, I think you can simply your call by using the `@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing` module the way you find in node.js example in [the Mailchimp
documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/). And you are importing Axios, but you are using `request` for the call. [That package seems to be deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey gabe. I tried the way mentioned in the documentation but I keep getting this error-
Error: Bad Request
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\Rupak\Desktop\Projects\Web Development\Newsletter-Signup\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:699:13)

and a bunch more stuff

Comment: Do you get an error object back from the server in the ‘response’, like you did before?

Comment: You have the `mailchimp.setConfig` in the get request. You should put that in the post request or at the top of the file, just below the import of the mailchimp module.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Apparently I can't do this directly

```
email_address: req.body.email,
status: "subscribed",
merge_fields: {
  FNAME: req.body.firstName,
  LNAME: req.body.secondName
}
```

I need to create an object of the user and store the values in it. Then I have to access the values from the object while adding a member to the list. Here's how I did it

```
email_address: subscribingUsers.email_address,
  status: "subscribed",
  merge_fields: {
    FNAME: subscribingUsers.firstname,
    LNAME: subscribingUsers.lastname,
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone told me why this is. Do we need a key-value pair while posting any data to the server? And if so, why doesn't it work by directly getting the values from the request?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
const data = {
  members: [{
    email_address: email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {
      FNAME: firstName,
      LNAME: lastName,
    }
  }]
}
```